# How to access and modify value of a struct which is a public member of a class (c++)

Tags: c++, templates

i would like to know how can i access and modify the struct's attributes in the constructor of my class. Thanks

```
template <class K, class V>
    class AVLTree
    {
        public:
            struct Node
            {
                Node *parent;
                Node *right;
                Node *left;
                int height;
            };
    // CONSTRUCTOR
            AVLTree(){
                Node::parent = NULL; // Access struct attributes here
            }
```

Comment: `struct Node {/*..*/};` just defines a inner class, You don't show any member of that kind in the `AVLTree`. `Node root;` or similar seems missing.

Comment: You need an instance of a `Node`, which I do not see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct`s, by themselves, are not entities of any kind, that have any kind of an attribute, or anything.

A `struct`, by itself, is just a definition for an object that claims to be that `struct`.

An object, of the `struct`'s type, will have the attributes and methods that are a part of the `struct`'s definition.

So, for example, if your `AVLTree` template has a member

```
Node n;
```

then the `AVLTree` constructor can set this member:

```
n.parent=nullptr;
```

However, that's not even the best way to do this. You will discover that the best way to avoid bugs in C++ code is to make it logically impossible for them to happen. Right now it is possible to forget to initialize `Node`'s members, and cause bugs because of that.

So, to fix that, have `Node` itself provide default values for its members, with its own constructor.

But it's not even necessary to do that, with modern C++, just define the default values for the attributes, or class members:

```
            struct Node
            {
                Node *parent=nullptr;
                Node *right=nullptr;
                Node *left=nullptr;
                int height=0;
            };

            Node n;
```

Now, nothing needs to be done in `AVLTree`'s constructor, and you automatically avoid all bugs due to uninitialized class members.